# Ошибка PyCharm невозможно создать проект не находит интерпретатор

Tags: python, pycharm

не понимаю в чём ошибка.
Создаю проект в Pycharm, версия Python 3.8, но выдаёт "ошибку создания интепретатора"

Ошибка выглядит так:

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"): CreateProcess error=5, Отказано в доступе

Переустанавливал и PyCharm и Python, как найти ошибку не знаю(

Comment: А поставьте его из офф сайта: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @gil9red спасибо помогло!

Comment: Создайте пожалуйста сами ответ с указанием что сделали, чтобы решить проблему :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто удалил весь Python. И скачал его с официального сайта python.org/downloads и все интерпретаторы встали на места.